# Password is being saved in the PHP session but when reloading the page it goes back to login form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, authentication, web

I created a controller and a view with a form in which you can enter a password. Using Middleware, I want to determine that this password is valid and save the password for the session.
If the password from the session is valid, the user needs to display not the form, but the page content.

Here are my routes, middleware and controller:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/login', 'login@show')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'login@checkPass')->name('check.pass')->middleware(PasswordAuthTask::class);
Route::get('/noaccess', 'login@checkPass')->name('noaccess')->middleware(PasswordAuthTask::class);
```

Middleware:

```
class PasswordAuthTask
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $request->session()->put('password', $password);
        $expectedPass = '123';

        if (($password === $expectedPass) || ($password === null || $password === '')) {
            if ($password === $expectedPass) {
                $request->session()->put('password', $password);
            }

            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('noaccess');
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class login extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        if (Session::has('password') && Session::get('password') === '123') {
            return view('content');
        }

        return view('login');
    }

    public function checkPass(Request $request)
    {
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $expectedPass = '123';
        if (Session::has('password') && $password === $expectedPass) {
            return view('content');
        } else {
            return view('noaccess');
        }
    }
}
```

Even with the password being correct and stored in the session, when reloading the page it goes back to the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, this should work. The session data will be persisted as long as the middleware is allowed to terminate.

Looks like the conditional:

```
if (($password === $expectedPass) || ($password === null || $password === ''))
```

may be preventing the call to $next.

Maybe something like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $request->session()->put('password', $password);
        $expectedPass = '123';

        if (($password === $expectedPass) || ($password === null || $password === '')) {
            if ($password === $expectedPass) {
                $request->session()->put('password', $password);
            }
        } else {
            return redirect('noaccess');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: That was it, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!